# Find the maximum of a SmoothKernelDistribution

Tags: mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to find the maximum of a PDF calculated using the `SmoothKernelDistribution` function.
I do so by solving the first order condition but Mathematica seems unable to solve it.
As a minimum working example, I've using so far the following:

```
data = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[4, 5], 10000];
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
Solve[D[PDF[dist,x]]==0,x]
```

The result I obtain is:

```
Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact 
coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of 
inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used 
by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of 
the system may help. >>
```

Moreover, `FindRoot` proposed as solution `{x -> 1.79065}`.
How should I proceed?

Comment: `Solve` and `D` are or symbolic computation.  Here you are dealing with numerical methods.  Use `FindMaximum`, `NMaximize`, `NArgMax`, etc.  Take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/12) before you start, in case it will become necessary.  Also try `FindMaximum[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0.5}]`.

Comment: I don't understand the question about `FindRoot`.  It seems to have given you the result.  Thus you have the location of the maximum.

Comment: Thanks,@Szabolcs! Regarding the `FindRoot` it gave an answer but completely off the domain of the function. About the numerical nature of the problem, I thought that the underlying structure of the `SmoothKernelDistribution` was a spline function. Anyway, I'd like to have an analytical result since this is part of a wider problem.

Comment: You are right.  `FindRoot` and `FindMaximum` have options to keep them within the domain, see the documentation.  E.g. `FindMaximum[..., {x, 0, 1}]`.  With `NMaximize` you can either use a constraint, `NMaximize[{PDF[dist, x], 0 < x < 1}, x]`, or a domain: `NMaximize[PDF[dist, Indexed[x, 1]], x \[Element] Interval[{0, 1}]]`.  In the second case `x` is considered a "1D vector", hence the need to index it.

Comment: About the numerical nature: Yes, the distinction between exact and numerical is sometimes blurred in Mathematica.  It is possible to get the exact derivative of an `InterpolatingFunction`.  But `Solve` cannot work with it.  It is possible in theory to convert it to an explicit piecewise polynomial and attempt symbolic manipulation, but it's not straightforward and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ways to approximately locate the maximum of the PDF. Let's generate the data and the associated distribution first:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            data = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[4, 5], 10000]];

dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
pdf = PDF[dist];
```

A plot of the PDF shows that it is unimodal, which makes things a lot easier.
[image: plot of the PDF]

In fact, the plotting functionality, through its powerful `MeshFunctions` option, allows one to approximately locate the maximum:

```
plt = Plot[pdf[x], {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
           MeshFunctions -> {pdf'[#] &}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image: plot of the PDF with marked maximum]

To find that point, we need to peer into the internal structure of the plot and extract the required coordinates. Here's one way to do this:

```
pmax = First[Cases[Normal[plt], Point[pt_] :> pt, ∞]]
   {0.420995139971432, 2.380119517396955}
```

Another method uses an *undocumented* property of a `DataDistribution[]` object. In particular, we can extract the "active" domain of such an object like so:

```
dom = dist["Domain"]
   Interval[{-0.07888027350955408, 1.031712484891653}]
```

which can then be fed to `FindMaximum[]`:

```
FindMaximum[pdf[x], Prepend[First[dom], x] // Evaluate]
   {2.3801667157377957, {x -> 0.4209951363383487}}
```

Still another method hinges on the fact that the PDF is internally represented as an `InterpolatingFunction[]`, which allows us to extract the interpolation points used by the function. `PeakDetect[]` can then be used to locate the maximum:

```
iF = First[Cases[pdf, _InterpolatingFunction, ∞, Heads -> True]];
x0 = First[Pick[First[iF["Coordinates"]], PeakDetect[iF["ValuesOnGrid"]], 1]];
{x0, pdf[x0]}
   {0.42099513633834723, 2.380166715737796}
```